# YouTube Video ID Regular Expression (RegEx)

Tags: ruby, regex, youtube

Unlike all of the examples I've found, I don't need to extract the video ID from a youtube.com string, embed, or similar. I'm simply trying to validate that what the user enters (a youtube video ID) as valid.

Example ID's...

- gyEpV_o7lSA
- dQw4w9WgXcQ
- 0N4qxgkXYX8
- cP4zgb9H3Cg

What's in common?

- They all have 11 characters
- Contains lower / uppercase letters, digits, and _
- They can be in any random order

  - Can start with letter, digit, or underscore

How can I validate that what the user enters (a youtube video ID) is formatted properly?

Comment: The `"-"` hyphen is also a valid YouTube ID char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!!(string =~ /\A[\w\d]{11}\z/)
```

will return `true` if `string` is correctly validated, `false` if not.

Comment: Regarding: `/\A[\w\d]{11}\z/`, The `\d` is unnecessary (the `\w` includes decimal digits).  Also, the `-` hyphen is a valid ID char. What you need here is: `/\A[\w\-]{11}\z/`